# SQL Query that SELECTS same date and time, but different venue

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is:

```
List the performance description, date, time and venue of performances such
that for each one of the performances, there exists another performance
with the same date and time but performed in a different venue.
```

I think the only table that needs to be used is:

```
CREATE TABLE PERFORMANCE (
PerformDateTime     timestamp   NOT NULL,
Venue       VARCHAR2(75),
PerformDesc VARCHAR2(75),
constraint PERFORMANCE_PKEY primary key (PerformDateTime, Venue)
);
```

I've tried the following SELECT statements:

```
SELECT PerformDesc,PerformDateTime,venue FROM PERFORMANCE
WHERE PerformDateTime IN (SELECT PerformDateTime FROM PERFORMANCE GROUP BY venue);
```

And:

```
SELECT PERFORMANCE.PerformDesc,PERFORMANCE.PerformDateTime,PERFORMANCE.venue
FROM PERFORMANCE GROUP BY (PERFORMANCE.PerformDateTime);
```

Both of this statements has the error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Would love some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT PerformDesc,PerformDateTime,venue FROM PERFORMANCE a
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM PERFORMANCE b where a.PerformDateTime=b.PerformDateTime
and a.venue <> b.venue)
```

Comment: May I know what does SELECT 1 do?

Comment: instead of selecting column it is efficient to select 1 as  this will only return row when date will be same and venue will be different @Azaqi

Answer (score 0):

use `exists`

```
   select t1.* from PERFORMANCE t1
   where exists ( select 1 from PERFORMANCE t2 
               where t2.PerformDateTime=t1.PerformDateTime
               and t2.venue<>t1.venue
              )
```

Comment: May I know what does SELECT 1 do?

Comment: it is better to to select constant value rather column thats why here 1 in selection

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. As your second select query has no sense of where condition, if you remove also same data will receive logically. if you want to group by, as all the columns are distinct so you must need to add the columns which are distinct in group by clause.
So later you can apply where clause depends on requirements.

```
SELECT distinct PERFORMANCE.PerformDesc,PERFORMANCE.PerformDateTime,PERFORMANCE.venue
    FROM PERFORMANCE GROUP BY PERFORMANCE.PerformDateTime,PERFORMANCE.PerformDesc,PERFORMANCE.PerformDateTime,PERFORMANCE.venue
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use such a `self-join` :

```
SELECT p1.PerformDesc, p1.PerformDateTime, p1.venue 
  FROM Performance p1
  JOIN Performance p2 ON ( p2.PerformDateTime = p1.PerformDateTime )
 WHERE p1.venue != p2.venue;
```